# ionic push notification implementation

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, push-notification, angularjs-scope

I am implementing push notification my push notification with ionic platform (ionic io) working properly now I have to take out that device token and send it to my server.
below is my ap.js code:

```
var push = new Ionic.Push({
      "debug": true
    });

    push.register(function(token) {
      console.log("My Device token:",token.token);
      push.saveToken(token);  // persist the token in the Ionic Platform

    });
```

This is my login for

```
$scope.login = function () {
$http({
method: "post",
url: "http://200.189.253.200:8081/employee-connect/oauth/token",
data: "username="+$scope.username+"&password="+$scope.password+"&grant_type=password&scope=read write&client_secret=my-secret-token-to-change-in-production&client_id=employeeConnectapp2",
withCredentials: true,
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
})
.success(function (data){
window.localStorage.setItem("token_type", data.token_type);
window.localStorage.setItem("token", data.access_token);
$state.go('tabsController.home');
})
.error(function(data) {
var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
title: 'Login failed!',
template: 'Please check your credentials!'
});
});
}
```

In the success call I have to send token by fetching it from console but don't know how to do. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

Install this plugin

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git
```

and inside your .run funtion do this

```
          var androidConfig = {
            "senderID": "xxxxxxxx", //you should place your gcm project number
          };

          document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
            $cordovaPush.register(androidConfig).then(function(result) {
              // Success
            }, function(err) {
              // Error
            })

            $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', function(event, notification) {
              switch(notification.event) {
                case 'registered':
                  if (notification.regid.length > 0 ) {
                    alert('registration ID = ' + notification.regid);
     //here you will see the device token in alert.

                    MyService.setDeviceID(notification.regid);

//here i have used MyService to access the regiser id inside my controller
                  }
                  break;

                case 'message':
                  // this is the actual push notification. its format depends on the data model from the push server
                  alert('message = ' + notification.message + ' msgCount = ' + notification.msgcnt);
                  break;

                case 'error':
                  alert('GCM error = ' + notification.msg);
                  break;

                default:
                  alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
                  break;
              }
            });



          }, false);
```

For more information of getting device id look [this](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/)

Look this answer that i have posted to get the Deal with GCM push notification [Ionic Push Notifications: getPushPlugin is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36564183/ionic-push-notifications-getpushplugin-is-undefined/36595867#36595867)

Comment: 1>register the app to push services and also

Comment: i don't understand you

Comment: sir i am new in this first i created app from ionic docs for push notification it works well but my requirements are now i have to use my server for sending notification how can i do this also i am confuse

Comment: about cordova and ionic

Comment: even though i send you my code in your case you will not able to understand try to understand what are all the requirement you will be needing to send a push notification and brake that task and implement one by one that can help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114917/discussion-between-mohan-gopi-and-rigel).